# Django - quiz app - issue with forms i guess

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make an app by using django which allow me to study.

for now I have already done it

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('test/<str:pk>/', views.test),
]
```

views.py

```
def test(request, pk):
    test = Test.objects.get(id=pk)
    questions = test.questions.all()
    form = Answer()
    context = {'questions':questions, 'form':form}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        instance = Question.objects.get(id=pk)
        form = Answer(request.POST, instance=instance)

        if form.is_valid():
            if request.POST.get("answer").strip() == instance.answer:
                return redirect('home')

    return render(request, 'exam/test.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class Answer(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['answer_text']
    answer = forms.CharField(label='Your answer', max_length=100)
```

and my html code:

```
{% for question in questions %}
        <div class="question-container">
            <p>{{question.question_text}}</p>
            <form method="POST">
                <td>{{ form.answer }}</td>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="{{ question.id }}" />
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit">
                </td>
            </form>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('exam.urls'), name="home"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I haven't implemeted any point counter function. I wanted to be redirected to home page if answer is correct to see if the form works corectly but it is not. Where did i make mistake ?

Comment: I will probably change my html code - i will remove submit button from loop and add one on the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

**Original Answer**

I believe the mistake is here:

```py
if request.POST.get("answer").strip() == instance.answer:
```

Which should be:

```
if request.POST.get("answer_text").strip() == instance.answer_text:
```

Your `instance` is a Question object, with a field `answer_text`, not `answer`.

Your root urls.py also has a path with 'name', and I don't think you want it there.

```py
# change
    path('', include('exam.urls'), name="home"),
# to this:
    path('', include('exam.urls')),
```

The name is already in your exam.urls.py.

**Edit**

I think your forms.py has an issue, since it's a ModelForm, the field is already given in the class, so you don't need the line defining `answer`:

```py
class Answer(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['answer_text']
    # Remove the line below:
    # answer = forms.CharField(label='Your answer', max_length=100)
```

Then in your template:

```html
{% for question in questions %}
    <div class="question-container">
        <p>{{question.question_text}}</p>
        <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <td>{{ form.answer_text }}</td>
            <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="{{ question.id }}" />
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </td>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And try to put the print statements as follows:

```py
def test(request, pk):
    print("Am I getting here?")  #check if the view is even being called
    test = Test.objects.get(id=pk)
    questions = test.questions.all()
    form = Answer()
    context = {'questions':questions, 'form':form}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("request.POST", request.POST)  # to check what is being sent by the form
        instance = Question.objects.get(id=pk)
        form = Answer(request.POST, instance=instance)

        if form.is_valid():
            print("form is valid")  # To check if the form is valid
            if request.POST.get("answer_text").strip() == instance.answer_text:
                print("answer is correct")  # to check if this logic is working
                return redirect('home')

    return render(request, 'exam/test.html', context)
```

**Edit 2**

Make sure to add the `print("request.POST", request.POST)`.  Since you're getting the "Am I getting here?", your path is fine.  Now do you get "Request.POST" in your terminal *when you click the submit button*?  If not, it probably means the html page is not going to the same path, in which case you need to tell it where to go by adding the action attribute to your form (this is **not** needed if `print(request.POST)` shows up):

```html
{% for question in questions %}
    <div class="question-container">
        <p>{{question.question_text}}</p>
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'test' question.pk %}">
            <td>{{ form.answer }}</td>   
                <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="{{ question.id }}" />
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </td>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, since pk is an integer, you should change the path to

```py
path('test/<int:pk>/', views.test),
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a mistake but I'm still not redirected. There is another issue

Comment: @KermitHQ, can you edit your question to add your root urls.py file, it might help, and maybe add `print(request.POST)` after the line, `if request.POST.get("answer").strip() == instance.answer_text:` to see if the issue is with the urls or with the logic.

Comment: I've just done it

Comment: @KermitHQ, it might be the root urls.py, which I've just edited, but if not, try to put in a print statement, like in my previous comment.

Comment: thanks for engagement but it also didn't help

Comment: i put print statement, but i don't know where should i look for printed value, I have never used it in django. In my main console after using python manage.py rusnerver nothing is printing

Comment: Okay, @KermitHQ, I think I've been confused by the `answer` and then the `answer_text`.  I've edited my answer, adding several print statements to help you narrow down the problem.  Sorry, I'm out of ideas.  Good luck.

Comment: @KermitHQ, I've edited my answer with a couple of suggestions, after I saw your updated question.